# Rewriting fraction as a derivative

Tags: temperature, electric-current, conductors

I have an equation which looks like this:
$${j^2} \frac{\rho_e}{c'} t=\Delta T$$
where $j$ is current's density, $\rho_e$ is conductor's electrical resistivity, $c'$ is heat capacity of conductor at constant volume, $t$ is time passed and $\Delta T$ is the change in conductor's temperature due electric current passing through it. If I divide both sides by $t$, then can I rewrite $\Delta T / t$ as $\partial T / \partial t$?

Comment: yes, for *very* short $t$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $t=\Delta t=t-0$, then one might write:
$${\Delta T\over\Delta t}=j^2{\rho\over c}.$$
Now if you take the limit, then you may write:
$$\lim\limits_{\Delta t\rightarrow 0}{\Delta T\over\Delta t}={d T\over dt}=j^2{\rho\over c}.$$
However, the argument depends on $t$ as the only variable in your equation, all the rest must be constant.
Now if $\Delta t$ is not small, then you have an expression for the *average* time rate of change instead of the instantaneous rate of change given by the derivative, i.e.
$${\Delta T\over \Delta t}=\text{average time rate of change for T}.$$